# Multi textured graphics

Tags: node-editor, uv-image-editor

I'm brand new to blender and am a bit dazzled by the node wrangler. I've been playing with texturing different parts of the mesh using downloaded textures etc. But when it comes to texturing the decals I get lost. Basically, I want to model this can

[image]

The aluminum can texture I'm using from Poliigon but on top of that, I want the label to have three layers to it like the image below

[image: print layers]

1. Bottom Layer. A translucent background pattern that combines with the texture and
   shade of the can ( a bit like how multiply works in
   photoshop/illustrator).
2. Middle Layer. An opaque, colour area that contains the main graphics. This needs
   to have a very subtle plastic texture to it
3. Top Layer. A textured spot varnish to most of the circular graphic, but not the
   words in the middle.

I've created a separate UV to the aluminum texture map the different layers to, but other than that I'm pretty lost. I'm assuming that I can use the black details shown in the link to define which areas have which texture but I can't figure out how to do that and I'm even more unsure about how these would then combine to make it look like the real-life can.

Comment: you need to load all these b&w pictures in Image Texture nodes, then use them as some sorts of "masks", think of them as photoshop masks, you just need to plug them into the factor socket of Mix Shaders, and plug the colors or nodes you want in the 2 Color sockets of these Mix Shaders

Comment: use the black and white images as **masks** to combine different shaders and/or colors the basic concept is explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447